# Signing a letter for a position you previously held

Tags: letter-writing

I need to write a letter of recommendation for past (adult) students of mine. I no longer hold the position as the institution went bankrupt. I want to include my previous title on the letter, how can I properly indicate I no longer hold the position?

I was thinking of these:

```
Mr. Foo Bar
Director, A. Department (former)
A Organization
```

or

```
Mr. Foo Bar
Director, A. Department (2014-2017)
A Organization
```

The letter does explain the organization is no longer in operation.

Comment: While both versions work, the dates make your point clear and solid.

Comment: Perhaps you should indicate that the institution is now defunct. A Organization (now defunct). Former is OK.But the dates are better, makes the defunct less awful. :)

Comment: The [signature block](https://support.clerky.com/articles/what-is-a-signature-block) provides context for your name. There is [an argument](http://www.formsofaddress.info/Retiree.html) that former *roles* (as opposed to *ranks*) are relinquished upon leaving the organisation. Your suggestions straddle a grey area by including both role and organisation, together with an indication that your affiliation was in the past. Consider placing that information within the body of your letter instead to provide relevance to your recommendation.

Comment: (Note: I wrote the above as a comment instead of submitting it as an answer because I think this question is off-topic on ELU and should be migrated to Workplace.SE. It's about the communication of a former work-related link between a former director and a former student, rather than about the English language.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're signing the letter, use the dates as recommended by @YosefBaskin.  But **omit "Mr."**

Alternatively, you can explain that you used to hold such-and-so position in such-and-so organization before it closed its doors, in the body of your letter.

Comment: Titles are omitted by convention in academic publications because it's the ideas that count, not the rank. In generic business (as is the case here), I'm not aware of any convention that says the title should be omitted.

Comment: @Lawrence - I'm not saying titles should be omitted from the text, if the text is talking about someone else.  I'm just saying that in the closing of a business letter, "Mr." and "Ms." are omitted.  Example: http://kawaiiro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Closing-In-Business-Letter-with-Passion-Dedication-Industry-Write-Dedicated-to-Perfoming-Your-Best-And-Extension-Industry-Free-Download-New-Example.gif

Comment: I was referring to citations and conventions regarding the styling of author names in the case of academic publications. Elsewhere, including signature blocks of a letter in a non-academic context such as the OP's, the title is [optional](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000155.htm). I'm not fussed if you omit the title as a matter of personal preference, but placing 'omit "Mr."' in bold, and as the only highlighted portion of your answer, seems to elevate it to the status of an agreed convention.

Comment: @Lawrence - Yup, you read my boldface correctly. I think the "Mr." in OP's question looks tacky.  // Your link doesn't quite support what I understood your position to be.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. My position I was trying to articulate is that titles aren't prohibited in signature blocks. After all, post-nominals are often appended, so why restrict titles? [Here's](http://www.wikihow.com/Sample/Business-Letter) an example of a wiki-how sample letter that includes the title in the signature block. In any case, it would help for you to link to a relevant authority in your answer if you consider the lack of titles in the signature block to be a convention.

Comment: @Lawrence - In my opinion, the Wiki-how sample letter looks tacky, and "Michael Smith, MD" would be much better. Perhaps you'd like to pose an ELU question about this?  I personally don't have an authoritative source to cite, and I didn't find your source convincing; but someone else might have a good source to cite.

Comment: I tend to agree, especially with "Mr.", which would only be useful if it was important to you (the writer) to specify your gender (and why would that be necessary in 2017?). Otherwise it does look tacky. There is no need to mention that the organization you worked for is now defunct; use of the dates of employment is the perfect way to avoid that altogether.